# how to do dynamic menu and content with ui.router?

Tags: angular-ui-router

I've been refactoring my site to use ui.router 1.* and component routing.

I came up with a solution see below. However I am wanting to know if this is the correct approach? I am not real happy about having $transitions injected into my master component but I am not sure how else I could achieve dynamic menu's.

I thought about defining these hooks in app.run but was unsure how to access or even if it was good practice to obtain master.menuComponents and alter.

Are there any down falls to do it this way?

index.html

```
<!docttype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--script stuff-->
    </head>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</html>



app.component('master', {
    bindings:   {menuComponents: '<'},
    template:   '<body>' +
                    '<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="naviation">' +
                        '<div class="navbar-header">' +
                            '<a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">My Dynamic Site</a>' +
                                '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">' +
                                    '<li ng-repeat="menu in $ctrl.menuComponents">' + 
                                        '<a ui-sref="{{menu.state}}" ui-sref-active="active">{{menu.name}}</a>' + 
                                    '</li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">' +                   
                        '</ul>' +
                        '<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">' +
                            '<li><a ui-sref="master.logout"><strong>logout</strong></a></li>' +
                        '</ul>' +
                    '</nav>' +
                    '<ui-view></ui-view>' +
                '</body>',
    controller: function(_, $transitions){
        var vm = this;


        $transitions.onExit({from: 'master.login'}, function(trans){
        //get new menu's and states based on credentials
                var $stateRegistry = trans.router.stateRegistry;
                $stateRegistry.register({name:'master.dynamic1', url:'/dynamic1', template: '<h1>I Am Dynamic</h1>'});
                vm.menuComponents.push({name:'dynamic1', state: 'master.dynamic1'});
        });

        $transitions.onEnter({to: 'master.logout'}, function(trans){

                var $stateRegistry = trans.router.stateRegistry;
                $stateRegistry.deregister('master.dynamic1');
                _.remove(vm.menuComponents, {name:'dynamic1'});

        });
    }
});

$stateProvider
    .state('master', {
        url: '/master',
        abstract: true,
        component: 'master',
        resolve: {
            menuComponents : function(){ //would probably inject a menuService to return this
                return [{name:'login', state: 'master.login'}];
            }
        }

    }).state('master.login', {
        url: '/login',
        component: 'login'
    }).state('master.logout', {
        url: '/logout',
        component: 'logout'
});

    $urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/master/login')
          .otherwise('/master/login');
```

Went ahead and set up a mongodb with menu documents i could load via a service into ui.router. everything seems good except for not being able to add states with components. I'm i going to have to lazy load for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

looks like git ui-router/sample-app-ng2 might provide a good starting point.